Default epsg used by jts geometry factory
When we create a geometry using a jts geometry factory what is the epsg used by it, i can see the srid there what its actual use
And let's say I have created the geometry how can I convert that geometry into epsg 4326
I have tried giving it srid as 4326 but I makes no change when geometries are created.

JTS doesn't care about projection so there's no srid set when geometries are created. You can set that value to any number you like but it will make no difference to the geometry.
If you need to handle projections and keep track of metadata related to the geometry you may want to look at the GeoTools library which is built on top of JTS.

So if i create the geometry using geometryshapefactory how can i convert that geometry into the EPSG:4326 using geotools, I am kind of new to geotools do you have any code snipped which will guide me through this process.

You can't convert a JTS geometry to a projected geometry, JTS has no concept of projection

So is there any way of creating a geometry using the geotools in the required projection like EPSG:4326

What projection are your data points in? Basically, your question is hard to answer because it doesn't really make sense in a geographic way
